# How to access the network file in command prompt?

Tags: windows, cmd

I have a **test.bat** file located at my desktop. When see the properties I can see the file is located at **\\mydir.adroot.dir\gb001\Path\Desktop\test.bat**

The challenging thing is, it is not mapped to any of the local drive something like (Z:).

How can I run/access the test.bat file in the command prompt?

Comment: open command prompt and cd to the desktop (your desktop is redirected to the UNC listed)

Comment: I couldn't even access the desktop. When I try to access, I'm getting **"The system cannot find the path specified."**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

open CMD  then drag an drop the bat file into CMD
 and hit enter key

Comment: Cool, it's working!! :)